# Use an array in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to use this array in `'select from..where..in(YYY)'` statement.

I don't want to iterate through array values, I want to use it **whole in my select statement**.

Unfortunately, I found only how to iterate it:

```
  1  declare
  2    type array is table of varchar2(30) index by binary_integer;
  3    a array;
  4    procedure p( array_in array )
  5    is
  6    begin
  7      for i in 1..array_in.count loop
  8        dbms_output.put_line( array_in(i) );
  9      end loop;
 10    end;
 11  begin
 12    a(1) := 'Apple';
 13    a(2) := 'Banana';
 14    a(3) := 'Pear';
 15    p( a );
 16  end;
 17  /
```

Comment: What is the background of your question? Depending on what you want to achieve, you might want to use one or anothere aprouch, for instance using bulk operations like forall i in array_in.first .. array_in.last
   UPDATE sometable SET a = b WHERE a = array_in(i);

Comment: @ErikL please write it in answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a ***`function`*** returning your array. Then you can use it into a select:

1. Create external types and function

---

```
create or replace type t_array is table of varchar2(30);

create or replace function list_of_fruits
    return t_array
  is
    l_ t_array:=t_array();
  begin
    l_.extend(); l_(l_.COUNT) := 'Apple';
    l_.extend(); l_(l_.COUNT) := 'Banana';
    l_.extend(); l_(l_.COUNT) := 'Pear';
    return l_;
  end list_of_fruits;
/
```

2. And here is how to use it:

---

```
select * from (
          select 'Peter' this_and_that from dual
union all select 'Joy'                 from dual
union all select 'God'                 from dual
union all select 'Pear'                from dual
union all select 'Man'                 from dual
  )
 where this_and_that in (
       select column_value from (table( list_of_fruits() )) 
 );
```

The trick here is to use the `table()` function to make a SQL usable list for your `select`; also difficult for me was to discover the name of that ***`column_value`***... which is some built-in constant from Oracle: how do you guess that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use oracle defined collection to achieve this as well. Please see below and example.

```
declare 

 a  sys.odcivarchar2list;

  begin
     a := sys.odcivarchar2list('Apple','Banana','Pear');

  for r in ( SELECT m.column_value m_value
             FROM table(a) m )
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line (r.m_value);
   end loop;
 end;
```